# VirtualBox runs as root, Critical Error as user

Tags: 14.04, permissions, virtualbox, software-installation, root

I've just done a fresh install of VirtualBox 4.3.10 on a relatively fresh install of 14.04 (Trusty) and am seeing the below error when attempting to start VB as a normal user

```
Failed to create the VirtualBox COM object.
The application will now terminate.
Callee RC: NS_BASE_STREAM_WOULD_BLOCK (0x80470007)
```

When I start as root, it appears to be working just fine. So, I'm guessing this is a permissions thing, but I don't know where to start as far as figuring out what exactly has the wrong permissions.

I've actually tried several different installation methods including the .deb's from oracle's website, Ubuntu Software Center, and via 'sudo apt-get install virtualbox'. I get the same result regardless of installation method.

Any ideas?

Comment: Perfect, thank you. Feel free to add this as answer so I can award you the points.

Comment: ok, I have added it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Deleting `~/.config/VirtualBox` should solve your problem.

Delete is using `rm -r ~/.config/VirtualBox` and start you virtual box. 
`

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem; it seems to have happened because my `~/.VirtualBox` folder was owned by `root`, and so I had lost write permissions.  Perhaps a consequence of running `sudo virtualbox` at some point.

The folder was empty, so I just deleted it with `sudo rm -d ...`, otherwise something like `sudo chown myname.myname ~/.VirtualBox` would fix the owner/group.

Answer (score 0):

This issue solved for me after removing the exported variable **VBOXSVC_RELEASE_LOG_DEST** from .bashrc file.

It is because I have added previously but now it is pointing to a non-existing path.
Also, This issue may occur if any of your path/directories used for virtual may have access denied or due to some changes may not exist.